# Find rows that match multiple (two) criteria

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I am trying to get a list of items that match on two criteria.

```
DATE     PRODUCT        CHANNEL
DEC 13   Cat Chow       DRUG
NOV 13   Pupperoni      DRUG
DEC 13   Meow Mix       DRUG
DEC 13   Jerky Treats   DRUG
```

This is the data from A1 to C5.  I want all the product sold on DEC 13 and in the DRUG channel. This is the formula that I have now, which is only bringing back the first example.

```
INDEX($B$2:$B$5,  MATCH(1, ("DRUG"=$C$2:$C$5)*("DEC 13"=$A$2:$A$5), 0) )
```

Answer (score -1):

You could add this to another column ...

> =IF(AND(A2="DEC 13", C2="DRUG"),B2, "")

and then select, copy and paste it down the column.

(Then, if you need to you can select that column, copy it, and do paste-special, just values to another column and then sort it and delete the blank cells that are all together.)

Comment: Wow, getting down-voted almost 4 years after posting the response.  :)